# Getting Electron to work with node's bluetooth-serial-port

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, electron

I'm trying to get my Windows Electron-App to establish a stable Bluetooth connection to another device ("normal" Bluetooth, not BLE). I already was stuck with installing node-gyp, but I finally got it to install properly (at least I think so). Now I'm stuck again and need some hints to keep on going.

I tried various different libs and nothing seemed to work for me. After trying to use node-bluetooth (failed at rebuilding it for electron) I decided to give bluetooth-serial-port a try. But I'm stuck again at the rebuilding problem.

I followed the suggestions from Bruce on [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/use-node-usb-inside-electron/16748/2) side (after trying a few other approaches) but had to stop when I should have changed the variables property in the bindings.gyp
Neither the Electron folder nor the bluetooth-serial-port folder contains this file (I installed them in different folders for the moment because otherwise they overwrite each other).

Trying to rebuild bluetooth-serial-port with `node-gyp rebuild --target=0.30.1 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell` failed with the following output:

```
$ node-gyp rebuild --target=2.0.2 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
gyp info using node@8.11.3 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\python27\python.EXE
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\sbraendle\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sbraendle\\Desktop\\Electron\\BluetoothTest\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sbraendle\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sbraendle\\.node-gyp\\iojs-2.0.2\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\sbraendle\\.node-gyp\\iojs-2.0.2',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\sbraendle\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\sbraendle\\.node-gyp\\iojs-2.0.2\\<(target_arch)\\iojs.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\sbraendle\\Desktop\\Electron\\BluetoothTest',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sbraendle\\Desktop\\Electron\\BluetoothTest\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Users\sbraendle\Desktop\Electron\BluetoothTest) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\sbraendle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\sbraendle\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=2.0.2" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sbraendle\Desktop\Electron\BluetoothTest
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

The actual setup is:

- Win 7 x64
- node 8.11.3
- node-gyp 3.7.0
- electron 2.0.2 (not entirely sure, but it says that at installation).

Alternatively I'm also open to other approaches on how to establish a Bluetooth connection with Electron as long as someone already got it to work.

---

I don't know what I did wrong yesterday, but today I reinstalled everything, and this time the installation of electron seemed to work properly as well as the installation of bluetooth-serial-port (or node-bluetooth which was my second try). I tried to run the app without adding any reference to Bluetooth. The program started properly. But as soon as I add a line like `const bluetooth = require('node-bluetooth');` it crashes in both cases (node-bluetooth and bluetooth-serial-port) with the following error:

```
$ npm start

> bluetoothtest@1.0.0 start C:\Users\sbraendle\Desktop\Electron\BluetoothTest
> electron .


App threw an error during load
Error: Das System hat keinen Meldungstext für die Meldungsnummer 0x%1 in der Meldungsdatei %2 gefunden.
\\?\C:\Users\sbraendle\Desktop\Electron\BluetoothTest\node_modules\node-bluetooth\build\Release\BluetoothSerialPort.node
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:671:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at bindings (C:\Users\sbraendle\Desktop\Electron\BluetoothTest\node_modules\node-bluetooth\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sbraendle\Desktop\Electron\BluetoothTest\node_modules\node-bluetooth\index.js:3:48)
```

Sorry for the German in the Error Message: I wanted to copy it exactly. Translation for this is:

> The system has not found any message text for the message number 0x% 1 in the message file% 2.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread was opened a year ago but I had the same problem this morning and finally made Electron to work with bluetooth-serial-port! So here are the steps:

1. Delete your `node_modules` folder and the `package.lock` file.
2. Open your terminal: `npm install --save-dev electron@4.2.6` and `npm install --save-dev  electron-rebuild`.

> Note: The version of electron should be that exact version. Recent
>   releases are built on Node 12 and this will fail to build the
>   bluetooth library. 
>   You can learn more here:
>   https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-releases

3. Also in your terminal: `npm install --save bluetooth-serial-port`. My version is 2.2.4 by the time of writing.
4. add this script to your package.json: 
   `"scripts":{"rebuild": "electron-rebuild"}`
5. In your terminal: `npm install` and then `npm run rebuild`
6. Your project should now compile and you have a working bluetooth-serial-port module inside of electron. I tested the module with an HC-06 tranceiver.

Comment: For reference only: the current NodeJs release installed on my machine is 10.16.0 . It is today the most stable version recommended for all users.

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution, even if this Question was asked long time ago. We did not get it to work within our time limitations, so we had to switch to another graphical framework.
We now use kivy, wich is ok, but sometimes a little bit complicated. Perhaps I'll give electron another shot on a private project.
Thanks for posting your solution. Perhaps it will help others to get their projects done.

Comment: I just tested this today and for electron-rebuild, this specific version will work: npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild@1.8.5